# Extracting and converting data from JSON via js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Good evening! There is a script that converts data into an array, I would like to know how it can be upgraded so that you can convert and extract data for each object (arb, astar, aurora, avax, baba, bsc, etc.), the data in the screenshot.

The script for converting data into an array (currently extracts only from bsc):

```
var data = {(Screenshot)};

var output = Object.keys(data.bsc.token_dict).map(k => data.bsc.token_dict[k]);
console.log(output);
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want the same structure as your original data, but with everything removed except token_dict.  Correct?

Comment: @James true, but there should be something like this structure (screenshot)
https://i2.paste.pics/e29bc36f772b2901b520e768c33e6a74.png?trs=c584a5647e502bd9961f792b11d8b023a75e174f7cddb0d60ce555e0ac01ae25

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
const output = Object.entries(data)
    .map((k, v) => ({chain: k, token_dict: Object.values(v.token_dict)}));
```